# Adding a SuccessHandler to an AuthenticationProvider in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring

#### How can I add a SuccessHandler to an AuthenticationProvider in a Spring application?

I made the following `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` from [baeldung tutorials](https://www.baeldung.com/):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private GatewayAuthenticationProvider authProvider;
    @Autowired
    private GatewayAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
    @Autowired
    private GatewayLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/welcome*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
        http.formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
            .successHandler(successHandler);
        http.logout()
            .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);

    }

}
```

As you can see the `.successHandler(successHandler)` method is applied after `.formLogin()`, so it seems to to configure form login and not custom login from the `AuthenticationProvider`.

But `.authenticationProvider(authProvider)` returns a `HttpSecurity` object, which does not have a `.successHandler(successHandler)` method.

Is the trick in the `AuthenticationProvider` class definition itself?

Comment: You don't. The different authentication mechanisms call the success or failure handler not the authenticationproviders. So the form login filter will call the success handler not the provided authentication provider/manager.

Comment: Yes but I would like to have my AuthenticationProvider be called on login instead of formlogin and then my SuccessHandler if login is successful. Can I do that?

Comment: form login isn't an authentiction provider. An authentication provider is a thing like DB, LDAP etc.

Comment: Yes but then is there a way to add an action after the authentication provider confirms that credentials are valid? Or the only way is to add it is directly in the code of the AuthenticationProvider?